# The optimised covering set problem

Tags: combinatorics

Consider all 0-1 bit strings of length n and the set $S_k=\{s_k:s_k$ contains k 1-bit and (n-k) 0-bit$ \}$ for $k \in [1,n]$. Define “s covers $q$” if and only if whenever $q(i)=1$ $\forall i \in [1,k]$, $s(i)=1$.
 **Example:** when $n=3,k=2$, $S_2=\{110,101,011\}$. Also $011$ covers $001$, $010$ and $000$. Also by defnition, $111$ covers all strings of length $3$. 
Here is my question: **pick a subset $Q_k \subseteq S_k$, $\forall p \in S_{k-1}, \exists q \in Q_k$ such that $q$ covers $p$. Also the number of $p \in S_{k-1}$ which is covered by more than $1$ element in $Q_k$ is minimised.**
This means in the best situation, for every $p \in S_{k-1}$, there is only $1$ element in $Q_k$ which covers $p$ and we want to select this $Q_k$. For example $n=5$, if we want to select $Q_4$ to cover every elements in $S_3$, $Q_4$ could be $\{11110, 11101, 11011\}$. In this case only 3 elements in $S_3$, which is $11100, 11001,11010$ is covered by more than $1$ element in $Q_4$ and this value is minimised.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a good algorithm, made a few examples by hand and it seems to work: start by listing all elements of $S_{k-1}$. Then, pick any element $q_1$ from $S_k$ and remove from your list all elements covered by $q_1$. Now select $q_2 \in S_k$ such that $q_2 \neq q_1$ and remove from the list all elements that are covered by $q_2$. Now select $q_3$ such that $q_3 \neq q_2, \, q_3 \neq q_1$ and remove from the list the elements covered by $q_3$... Repeat until you have no elements left.
The problems that may seem to come with this construction look like they're unavoidable. By that, I mean selecting lots of $q_i$ that have $1$ in the same position: this might be intrinsic to the requirements.

Comment: Yes but can you give a statistical analysis about how much the size $Q_k$ should be?